# C# Modify objects in a list of objects

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects returning from a function.
How I can traverse the list and modify some objects, like append a specific string
to all cells (integers) of a specific column? I could also add 2 more string columns: sid_s and num_s if its easier...

```
List<object> data = (from q in dc.Queries
                                 join ss in dc.Sites on q.SiteId equals ss.Siteid
                                 where q.CTid == 100
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     s.id, //integer to string
                                     q.name,
                                     q.num
                                 }).ToList<object>();
```

Here is my list:

> sid | name | num
>
> 100 | a    | 2001
>
> 101 | b    | 2002

I want to change it to:

> sid | name | num
>
> 100qq | a    | 2001zz
>
> 101qq | b    | 2002zz

OR

> sid | name | num | sid_s | num_s
>
> 100 | a    | 2001| 100qq |2001zz
>
> 101 | b    | 2002| 101qq |2002zz

Comment: You can use `for` or `foreach` loop. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)** and loop through the list :

```
foreach(MyObject obj in myList)
{
   obj.yourProp1 = "newValue";       
}
```

Comment: please see my example

Comment: post how you generate the list

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: IMO the solution of @Sajeetharan will not work since foreach generates a copy of the original object (MyObject) and the code is manipulating the copy, not the original instance.